# Eclipse: use environment variables in "Java build path"

Tags: eclipse

I am using the eclipse variables in order to define the path of the libraries in the "java Build Path" of the eclipse project like:

BASELOCATION/dir1/lib1.jar
BASELOCATION/dir1/lib2.jar
BASELOCATION/dir2/lib3.jar

The issue here is that I have to define this variable every time, I am changing the BASELOCATION or I am creating the new Workspace.

Using of the system environment variables should really help, but I didn't find a way to do that.

Any other idea, even the way I could set these variables using some custom script is appreciated.

Thanks for your help!